# (java)If enum is static - how is it that another instance is created in my code (using DB40) ?

Tags: java, enums, db4o

In my code I have the following enum

```
public ennum BuySell {
  buy('B', true, RoundingMode.DOWN, 1),
  sell('S', false, RoundingMode.UP, -1 buy);


  BuySell(char c, boolean isBuy, RoundingMode roundingMode, int mult) {
     this.aChar = c;
     this.isBuy = isBuy;
     this.isSell = !isBuy;
     this.roundingMode = roundingMode;
     this.mult = mult;
  }

  BuySell(char c, boolean isBuy, RoundingMode roundingMode, int mult, BuySell   oppositeAction) {
     this(c, isBuy, roundingMode, mult);

     this.opposite = oppositeAction;
     oppositeAction.opposite = this;
  }
}
```

I save objects containing this enum through DB40 and when my system loads it loads those objects. 
what I see is that the loaded objects contain ButSell with different object id .
Here you go :

[image]

you can see that one selling = 9570 and the other is 9576

My quoestion is - how does another instance of this enum is created ? isnt it static ?

How can I avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: My advice, don't store enums with db4o. The way db4o stores enums has tons of fallpits, issues etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get multiple instances if

- You have multiple class loaders.
- You use `Unsafe` to create an instance of an Enum class.

Further investigation would be required to determine how to avoid this. e.g. Are you setting the class loader. Is the ClassLoader for the two object different? Does the library use Unsafe.allocateInstance ?

BTW: I would use BUY and SELL rather than buy and sell for enum constants.

Comment: Thanks. I am not changing the class loaders. but maybe db40 jars do. BTW: regarding your BTW : what do you mean  "use BUY and SELL" ? Strings ?

Comment: He means that enum values should be capitalized (BUY, SELL instead of buy, sell).

Comment: You are not changing the ClassLoaders, but the library could be. I would check the class loader for the different instances.

Answer (score 0):

You have now two instances of your enum: `buy` and `sell`. And *they* are static. Not your `BuySell` type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a factory and in your objects in setBuySell go through factory. I don't know DB40 so it's a wild guess